# query the html taken from PHP's file_get_contents using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, file-get-contents

If I have

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.some-url.com/index.php');
```

how do I query the html using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to output the HTML onto the page then use jQuery to query it once the page is loaded.

Comment: and if you don't want to show $html in you page you can add it to an invisible div.